# If I make a non-verbatim quotation (as news outlets often do in their titles), what punctuation should I use?

Tags: punctuation, quotations

> Federal judge Beryl A. Howell: No vote on initiating an inquiry is required. In the cases of all three presidents who faced such an action — Andrew Johnson, Richard M. Nixon, and Bill Clinton — the House Judiciary Committee had begun investigating or received grand jury materials before a full House vote.

It gets tricky when there's more than one sentence. The way I wrote it doesn't make it clear that the second sentence is also what the judge, not me, said. If I use quote marks, then I would mislead a reader into believing that it's an actual word-for-word citation when it's not the case. I could use semicolons, but imagine there're three or more sentences. I don't want to make some sentence centipedes like some sick linguo-surgeon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no punctuation mark that specifically indicates non-verbatim quotation. Since you're not primarily concerned with space constraints the way newspaper headings are, I'd suggest adding a verb.

> "Federal judge Beryl A. Howell **argues/opines/suggests/claims that** no vote... **She cites** the precedent of the three presidents who faced..."

Comment: Yes, I’d expect a verb rather than a colon. But, for a headline style (headlinese) I’d expect commas rather than ‘period + new sentence”, For example, *High Court rules Aboriginal people cannot be deported for criminal convictions, cannot be 'alien' to Australia.*